# Modify Keys on Microsoft Naturals Ergonomic 4000 Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

Is it possible to assign one of my "favorites" buttons on my keyboard to mimic my mouse right click?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be my answer to everything these days ;)

try http://www.autohotkey.com/ it can configure any key to click a mouse button amongst many other things.

Comment: needed a 30 mins or so to dig into doc to find it but you can remap special keys i.e. "Browser_Back::"

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these projects, I know they can all remap keys but I am not sure if they can generate a mouse click event as you have described:

- [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/)
- [KeyTweak](https://archive.org/details/tucows_327616_KeyTweak)
- [HotKey Control](https://inchwest.com/hotkeycontrol/)

Answer (score 1):

I think it only takes applications. Although if you wanted to click wtih you keyboard look under accessibility (ease of use in windows 7). select "use mouse keys". This way 5 on your num pad becomes a right-click.

Although shift+f10 already does this. Can key combos be mapped to your "favorites" keys?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [**Microsoft IntelliPoint Pro 8.0**](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000) software?  I have a Microsoft Media Center keyboard which is very configurable from in the IntelliPoint software, but you will have to check to see whether it can be set to right-click on yours, if it does not have a right-click button as standard.

Answer (score 1):

The standard [Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center) doesn't let you assign mouse right click action to the favorites keys, but it does allow to set it on other keys, e.g. choose "Search Button" and then choose the radio button "Macro" and choose "right mouse click".

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is but only if you have installed the software that comes with it.**
Open "Microsoft Keyboard", select the "key settings" tab, select the key you want to attach a macro to (not all keys can have a macro assigned this way), click on the "Assign/Manage Macro" button. Go to the "Insert Special" drop-down list and select "Mouse Button 2". Save and close. Now when you highlight an object, pressing the programmed button will mimic a right button click.

Comment: While this answer is correct for most of the keys, it doesn't apply to the "My Favourites" keys.